# Bake textures in cycles and and used in Eevee vs Light Probes

Tags: eevee-render-engine, baking

I'm wondering what is the differences between these two approaches,

I managed to bake in cycles and used these textures in Eevee, and it looks almost the same, then what is the benefit of using Light Probes in Eevee? Only for animation? If my scene i static, does that mean they are exchangable?

Comment: I think it's a high, middle, low situation here. Real time raytrace in Cycles would be the slowest approach but would track real-time light movements. EEVEE with LP would be the middle ground solution, because even though it is a "baked light" operation, it is calculated significantly faster than cycles, and is therefore suitable to be baked on a per-frame basis (without the need for a render farm) Lastly, for scenes with truly static lighting, you can go either-or depending on your render engine of choice - Cycles is more realistic but slower - EEVEE with LP is faster, but still approximated.